# If HTML of a Div contains Response, write HTML to another Element, else Hide

Tags: jquery, html, append, show-hide, contains

On the back end, an admin can choose whether or not a training is mandatory by choosing Yes or No. The choice inserts "Yes" or "No" in a hidden div on the front end with class "check-yes".

I am trying to use jQuery to check this response and then write "Mandatory" (if Yes) in a particular p tag with class "mandatory" OR hide the p tag (if No). I can't seem to get this to work. There are multiple trainings on a page, so I need this to run per instance.

```
<div class="training">
<div class="hide check-yes">Yes</div>       
   <p>Training Title</p>
   <p class="mandatory"></p>
   <p>December 13th, 2013</p>
   <p>2:00pm to 4:00pm @ Emory House</p>   
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
 $('.training').each(function(){
    if($('.check-yes:contains("Yes")'))
        $('.mandatory').html('Mandatory');
    else 
        $('.mandatory').hide(); 
 });
 </script>
```

What am I missing? I thought I could modify other if/else hide div tricks I've used before but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.mandatory').text(function() {
    return $.trim( $(this).siblings('.check-yes').text()) == 'Yes' ? 'Mandatory' : '';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gg3Wn/)

Comment: Thank you. That definitely worked. Now I just need to study this some and understand the logic!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.training').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('.check-yes:contains("Yes")')){
      $(this).find('.mandatory').html('Mandatory');
   } else {
      $(this).find('.mandatory').hide();
   }
});
```

EDIT:

```
$('.training').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('.check-yes:contains("Yes")').length);
   if($(this).find('.check-yes:contains("Yes")').length > 0){
      $(this).find('.mandatory').html('Mandatory');
   } else {
      $(this).find('.mandatory').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding @sirikon! "Mandatory" is still being written regardless of scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I see now why it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that checks with find for the check-yes in it's context and hides or add text to the .mandatory in the same context.

```
(function($){
$('.training').each(function(){
    var training = $(this),
        mandatory = training.find('.mandatory'),
        check = training.find(".check-yes").text();
    if(check.indexOf("Yes") >= 0){
        mandatory.html('Mandatory');
    } else { 
        mandatory.hide();
    }
 });
}(jQuery));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sekb9/)